# printing data under / hidden with html hover code option

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, printing

How can I print the numbers that are on a webpage that require you to hover over them to view it like the ones found on the better business website.

Example:
http://www.bbb.org/raleigh-durham/accredited-business-directory/roofers

I go to the website but I have to hover over the phone icon to view the phone number.  How can I make these phone numbers visible all at once so I can print them all on one document?

Thanks

Comment: Although this doesn't seems to be a programming related issue to me, you could go in the developer concole of your browser and enter: `jQuery('[itemprop="phone"]').parent('div').show();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly a stackoverflow question, but here is the solution copy&paste this line into the URL **after** the page loaded:

```
javascript:jQuery('.phone-link div:first-child').hide();jQuery('.phone-link div:last-child').show()
```

(include the `javascript:` at the beginning).

> note - you need to **replace** the current url (`www.bbb...`) with the one in the code-block above.

Comment: Thanks I tried www.bbb.org/raleigh-durham/accredited-business-directory/roofers?javascript:jQuery('.phone-link div:first-child').hide();jQuery('.phone-link div:last-child').show()    but I'm still required to mouse over the phone link to view it.   If this question doesn't belong here where should it be posted?

Comment: no no :) after you load the original page - replace the URL with the one I gave you.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div data-num="123456" class="phone">phone<div>
<script>
$(".phone").on('mouseover',function(){
    $(this).html($(this).attr("data-num"));
});
$(".phone").on('mouseout',function(){
    $(this).html("phone");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.